# como quitar la forma por defecto de un <button>

Tags: html, css

quiero quitar la forma por defecto de un button que es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cuadro blanco es la forma por defecto de un button, quiero quitarlo, para que solo me quede las 3 rayas, que es un icono, mi codigo es el siguiente:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="botonMenu"><i class="fas fa-bars" id="barsMenu"></i></button>
```

CSS:

```
#itemsMenu #barsMenu {
     font-size: 25px;
     border-radius: 2px;
     color: steelblue;
     z-index: 10;
  }

  #itemsMenu .botonMenu {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

**El #barsMenu son las 3 rayas, y el .botonMenu es el boton**

Ya intente con opacity pero, le da opacidad al icono también

Comment: Pensé en un opacity, pero le da opacidad al icono también @BetaM

Comment: -Listo.. @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las propiedades en este caso que aplicaremos son:

- background-color
- border como un atajo de:

  - border-width
  - border-color
  - border-style

La primera recibirá como valor `transparent`, mientras que la segunda recibirá un valor de `none`; de esta forma dejamos sin color de fondo al botón y sin la línea de borde al elemento.

Código:

```html
    <style>
      .botonMenu {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
      }
    </style>
    
    <button type="button" class="botonMenu">mucho mucho texto</button>
```

**Referencias**

- [Colores y fondos en CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/colors.html#propdef-background-color)
- [Bordes en CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Comment: Muchas gracias.